Speeding Up Monte Carlo Simulations for Weather-Dependent Claims
I’m working on a Monte Carlo simulation project, and I need help optimizing some aspects of the problem. Here’s the scenario :
We model claims R (linked to weather-dependent events) as independent variables, with the weather conditions themselves being independent under certain assumptions. The situation involves two hypotheses regarding motorcyclists :

Hypothesis A: All motorcyclists travel in the same region, subjected to the same weather conditions.

Hypothesis B: Motorcyclists travel in different regions, each with independent weather conditions (modeled as independent Markov chains).


The claim amounts (in monetary units) follow the distribution $\mathbb{P}r$ with density proportional to :
$f^*(x) = \textbf{1}{\mathbb{R}_+} \exp\left(-\eta\ln(\alpha + |x - x_0|)\right)$,
Where $\alpha > 0, x_0 > 0, \eta > 0$ are constants.
Over a period of 365 days, we insure $N$, and and the total claim amount $R$ is the sum of individual claims.
I aim to approximate the conditional expectation $m(s) = \mathbb{R}[R - s \mid R > s]$ using a Monte Carlo method.
Here’s the current R code I’ve written for simulating claim amounts based on $\mathbb{P}_r$ :
rremb <- function(n, params) {
  # Extract parameters from the list
  alpha <- params$alpha
  x0 <- params$x0
  eta <- params$eta
  
  # Check parameter validity
  if (alpha <= 0 | x0 <= 0 | eta <= 3) {
    stop("Invalid parameters: alpha > 0, x0 > 0, and eta > 3 are required")
  }
  
  # Normalization factor K
  K <- 2 * alpha^(1 - eta) / (eta - 1)
  
  # Inverse of F* (without normalization factor)
  F_star_inv <- function(z) {
    if (z <= 0.5) {
      return((alpha + x0 - (z * (eta - 1))^(1 / (1 - eta))))
    } else {
      return((x0 - alpha + ((1 - z) * (eta - 1))^(1 / (eta - 1))))
    }
  }
  
  # Inverse of F considering K
  F_inv <- function(y) {
    return(F_star_inv(K * y))
  }
  
  # Generate n uniform random values on (0, 1)
  u <- runif(n)
  
  # Use F_inv to generate values based on P_r
  x <- sapply(u, F_inv)
  
  return(x)
}

# Parameters
params <- list(alpha = 2.0, x0 = 50.0, eta = 4.0)

# Simulate values
n <- 100000  # Adjust as needed
simulated_values <- rremb(n, params)

# Display results
print(head(simulated_values, 10))

# Optional: Plot histogram of simulated values
hist(simulated_values, breaks = 50, main = "Histogram of Simulated Values", 
     xlab = "Values", ylab = "Frequency", col = "skyblue")


While the code works correctly, it’s not as fast as I’d like for large simulations. Is there a way to speed it up? For example:

Could the sapply call be replaced with something faster?

Is there a way to vectorize or optimize the F_inv function?


Thank you for your help!
Attention : The support of x is $\mathbb{R}_+$

@Rui Barradas answer is already better, but to answer your question 1. If you find yourself in a situation where you truly cannot use vectorized functions, you can try replacing apply family functions with a parallel library like furrr

Update 2
For the updated question that specifies x > 0, a quick fix is to implement rejection sampling. It will generally have a small impact on sampling speed compared to the first updated answer. Worst case (x0 ~ 0), it would be about twice as slow.
params <- list(alpha = 2, x0 = 1, eta = 3.1)

rremb6 <- function(n, params) {
  # Check parameter validity
  with(
    params,
    if (alpha <= 0 | x0 <= 0 | eta <= 3) {
      stop("Invalid parameters: alpha > 0, x0 > 0, and eta > 3 are required")
    } else {
      p <- 1 - (1 + x0/alpha)^(1 - eta)/2
      ns <- 0
      x <- numeric(n)
      while (n > 0) {
        np <- ceiling(n/p)
        xp <- x0 + sign(runif(np, -0.5, 0.5))*alpha*expm1(rexp(np, eta - 1))
        xp <- xp[xp > 0]
        if (length(xp) > n) xp <- xp[1:n]
        x[(ns + 1):(ns <- ns + length(xp))] <- xp
        n <- n - length(xp)
      }
      x
    }
  )
}

system.time(x <- rremb6(36e6, params))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    3.58    0.30    3.87
length(x)
#> [1] 36000000
any(x < 0)
#> [1] FALSE


Update
rremb does not correctly sample from the probability density given in the question introduction. Below is a function that correctly samples from the proportional density exp(-eta*log(alpha + abs(x - x0))).
rremb5 <- function(n, params) {
  # Check parameter validity
  with(
    params,
    if (alpha <= 0 | x0 <= 0 | eta <= 3) {
      stop("Invalid parameters: alpha > 0, x0 > 0, and eta > 3 are required")
    } else x0 + sign(runif(n, -0.5, 0.5))*alpha*expm1(rexp(n, eta - 1))
  )
}

The density is symmetric about x0, so the variates should have a mean close to x0. A quick check to show that rremb5 behaves as expected, while rremb does not:
params <- list(alpha = 2.0, x0 = 50.0, eta = 4.0)
mean(rremb(1e6, params))
#> [1] 49.61773
mean(rremb5(1e6, params))
#> [1] 49.99987

Check the speed of rremb5:
system.time(rremb5(63e6, params))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    4.10    0.15    4.23

For the distribution of sums of large numbers of these random variates, the central limit theorem does well since the distribution is already symmetric. By n = 1e4 the mean is essentially indistinguishable from a normal distribution:
(seed <- sample(.Machine$integer.max, 1))
#> [1] 2111216523
set.seed(seed)

system.time(x <- rremb5(1e8, params))
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    6.01    0.31    6.33
R <- rowMeans(`dim<-`(x, c(1e4, 1e4)))
sigma <- with(params, alpha*sqrt(eta/(eta - 3)/length(R))/(eta - 2))

Quick check for normality:
ks.test(R, pnorm, mean = params$x0, sd = sigma)
#> 
#>  Asymptotic one-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
#> 
#> data:  R
#> D = 0.0075364, p-value = 0.621
#> alternative hypothesis: two-sided

plot(ecdf(R), col = "blue", xlim = c(49.9, 50.1))
curve(pnorm(x, params$x0, sigma), 49.9, 50.1, col = "orange", add = TRUE)



Original Answer
Squeezing out a little more performance (compared to @RuiBarradas' answer):
rremb4 <- function(n, params) {
  eta1 <- params$eta - 1
  
  # Check parameter validity
  if (params$alpha <= 0 | params$x0 <= 0 | eta1 <= 2) {
    stop("Invalid parameters: alpha > 0, x0 > 0, and eta > 3 are required")
  }
  
  K <- 2/params$alpha^eta1
  u <- runif(n, 0, K)
  params$x0 + if (K > eta1/2) {
    s <- sign(eta1/2 - u)
    s*(params$alpha - (eta1*(s < 0) + s*u)^(-s/eta1))
  } else {
    params$alpha - u^(-1/eta1)
  }
}

Testing
params <- list(alpha = 2.0, x0 = 50.0, eta = 4.0)
n <- 100000

set.seed(2024)
v0 <- rremb(n, params)
set.seed(2024)
v3 <- rremb3(n, params)
set.seed(2024)
v4 <- rremb4(n, params)

identical(v0, v3)
#> [1] TRUE
all.equal(v0, v4)
#> [1] TRUE

Benchmark 1
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  original = rremb(n, params),
  rremb3 = rremb3(n, params),
  rremb4 = rremb4(n, params)
) |> print(order = "median", unit = "relative")
#> Unit: relative
#>      expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
#>    rremb4  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000 1.000000   100
#>    rremb3  1.107398  1.160999  1.155243  1.156929  1.152521 1.695537   100
#>  original 12.326559 13.862971 14.206785 14.728450 15.586803 6.436684   100

Benchmark 2 (K > eta1/2)
params <- list(alpha = 0.9, x0 = 50.0, eta = 4.0)
set.seed(2024)
v3 <- rremb3(n, params)
set.seed(2024)
v4 <- rremb4(n, params)
all.equal(v3, v4)
#> [1] TRUE

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  rremb3 = rremb3(n, params),
  rremb4 = rremb4(n, params)
) |> print(order = "median", unit = "relative")
#> Unit: relative
#>    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#>  rremb4 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100
#>  rremb3 1.043331 1.074695 1.131025 1.097187 1.126365 1.554966   100

Additional Checks
In response to the comment that the results (in form of histograms) are different to what the original code produced: the sampling performed by rremb4 is algebraically equivalent to that of rremb. Some additional checks to demonstrate:
f <- function(x) {
  seed <- sample(.Machine$integer.max, 1)
  set.seed(seed)
  v0 <- rremb(100, x)
  set.seed(seed)
  v4 <- rremb4(100, x)
  isTRUE(all.equal(v0, v4))
}

expand.grid(alpha = log(1:5) + 0.9, x0 = 50, eta = log(1:5) + 4) |>
  asplit(1) |> lapply(as.list) |> lapply(f) |> unlist() |> all()
#> [1] TRUE

Also, I'll point out that if alpha < ((eta - 1)/2)^(1/(1 - eta)), then the samples can include NA since z > 1 is a possibility, resulting in a negative value for (1 - z) * (eta - 1), for which there are no real roots.

Great ! But the histograms don't track correctly like in my original code.

How to correct that ?

For the same random seed, rremb4 returns results equal to (within the expected precision) rremb -- see the update. What parameter values are giving you histograms that aren't "correct"?

rremb4 is of good quality, however, in terms of time, we really need to optimize it..
We can do it faster it seems to me.
Thank you @jblood94

Looking again at your expression for the density, your formulation is equivalent to a double Lomax distribution, with shape parameter equal to eta - 1, scale parameter equal to alpha, and then a location parameter x0. Your rremb does not properly sample from that density. Instead, eta1 <- 1 - eta; K <- alpha^eta1; u <- runif(n, -K, K); x0 + sign(u)*(abs(u)^(1/eta1) - alpha) would correctly sample from the specified density.

In fact f* is not necessarily a density, which is why I normalized it by calculating K
And I have f*/K and its graph overlaps with the histogram perfectly with the histogram of rremb4 and that's great !
What I want now is how to make rremb4 even more efficient.

Yes, indeed. I will continue with rremb4.

I realize that exp(-eta*log(alpha + abs(x - x0))) is not normalized, but it's clearly the kernel of a shifted double Lomax distribution. Neither rremb nor rremb4 correctly sample from that density. An even faster version that does correctly sample: x0 + sign(runif(n) - 0.5)*alpha*expm1(rexp(n, eta - 1)). The distribution is symmetric about x0, so the mean of the variates should be very near x0.

Could you modify it in your rremb4 code please

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

For the distribution of R with large n, a normal approximation works very well. See the latest update.

Attention !
For alpha = 2.0, x0 = 1, eta = 3.1, the rremb5 and rremb4 functions return negative or outlier values

You didn't specify the support for x. The unnormalized density function you provided is valid for all real values of x. If x0/alpha (the location parameter divided by the scale parameter) is close to 0, then of course you will get negative values. Like I said, the distribution is symmetric about x0. If the support is supposed to be on the positive reals, the answer (and question) would need to be modified to reflect that.

Yes, the support of x is \mathbb{R}, it seems to me that this is translated in the statement by : $f^*(x) = \textbf{1}{\mathbb{R}} \exp\left(-\eta\ln(\alpha + |x - x_0|)\right)$ isn't it ?

Not at all. Because of the absolute value, you can plug in any value for x and you will get a valid probability density. That expression can be integrated over all reals. That is why I referred to it as a double Lomax--similar to a double exponential distribution.

ok, I will specify in the statement then.

Can this include other conditions?

Check out the latest update.

Hello @jblood94, I didn't understand how you got n1 <- ceiling(exp(7/sqrt(n))*n/(1 - (1 + x0/alpha)^(1 - eta)/2)) in rremb6 and why did you put [x > 0][1:n]

As I mentioned, rremb performs rejection sampling. x[x > 0][1:n] gives the first n samples that are accepted (after rejecting any negative variates).

For the rejection sampling, I used the distribution defined over all reals as the proposal distribution. Any negative values are simply rejected, and the resulting sample values are from the target distribution. The formula for n1 (the number of samples to take from the proposal distribution) was determined empirically so that there would be a near-zero probability of accepting less than n of the n1 samples.

Thank you so much ! But I would like to see this empirical process that leads us to this formula if possible.

Just sample until you get the needed number of samples. I modified the latest update. Easier to explain/follow.

Here are two versions of your function, both of them one order of magnitude faster.

The first, rremb2, vectorizes the if instruction with ifelse;
the second, rremb3, vectorizes with a logical index on the if condition. This gives a marginal speed-up of 4% over rremb2.

And there is no need for two F_*_inv, just pass the product K * y to F_star_inv. directly.
rremb2 <- function(n, params) {
  # Extract parameters from the list
  alpha <- params$alpha
  x0 <- params$x0
  eta <- params$eta
  
  # Check parameter validity
  if (alpha <= 0 | x0 <= 0 | eta <= 3) {
    stop("Invalid parameters: alpha > 0, x0 > 0, and eta > 3 are required")
  }
  
  # Normalization factor K
  K <- 2 * alpha^(1 - eta) / (eta - 1)
  
  # Inverse of F* (without normalization factor)
  F_star_inv <- function(z) {
    ifelse(z <= 0.5,
      (alpha + x0 - (z * (eta - 1))^(1 / (1 - eta))),
      (x0 - alpha + ((1 - z) * (eta - 1))^(1 / (eta - 1)))
    )
  }
  
  # Generate n uniform random values on (0, 1)
  u <- runif(n)
  # Use F_inv to generate values based on P_r
  x <- F_star_inv(u * K)
  
  x
}
rremb3 <- function(n, params) {
  # Extract parameters from the list
  alpha <- params$alpha
  x0 <- params$x0
  eta <- params$eta
  
  # Check parameter validity
  if (alpha <= 0 | x0 <= 0 | eta <= 3) {
    stop("Invalid parameters: alpha > 0, x0 > 0, and eta > 3 are required")
  }
  
  # Normalization factor K
  K <- 2 * alpha^(1 - eta) / (eta - 1)
  
  # Inverse of F* (without normalization factor)
  F_star_inv <- function(z) {
    res <- numeric(length(z))
    i <- z <= 0.5
    res[i] <- alpha + x0 - (z[i] * (eta - 1))^(1 / (1 - eta))
    res[!i] <- x0 - alpha + ((1 - z[!i]) * (eta - 1))^(1 / (eta - 1))
    res
  }
  
  # Generate n uniform random values on (0, 1)
  u <- runif(n)
  # Use F_inv to generate values based on P_r
  F_star_inv(u * K)
}

# Parameters
params <- list(alpha = 2.0, x0 = 50.0, eta = 4.0)
# Adjust as needed
n <- 100000

# Simulate values setting the pseudo-RNG seed so that results are reproducible.
set.seed(2024)
simulated_values <- rremb(n, params)
set.seed(2024)
simulated_values2 <- rremb2(n, params)
set.seed(2024)
simulated_values3 <- rremb3(n, params)

# compare results
identical(simulated_values, simulated_values2)
#> [1] TRUE
identical(simulated_values, simulated_values3)
#> [1] TRUE

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  original = rremb(n, params),
  rremb2 = rremb2(n, params),
  rremb3 = rremb3(n, params)
) |> print(order = "median", unit = "relative")
#> Unit: relative
#>      expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#>    rremb3  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000 1.0000000   100   b
#>    rremb2  1.041313  1.020075  1.017987  1.043388  1.033261 0.5482928   100   b
#>  original 11.501961 12.281259 12.611460 12.976389 13.417170 6.5469023   100  a

Created on 2024-11-23 with reprex v2.1.1

Barrabas, Thank you very much.
I have friends who are at 8 seconds for 63 million simulations..
Is it possible to do better than them?

Is the use of pseudo-random sequences with low discrepancy, Halton sequences, quasi Monte Carlo, etc.? could help to do better?

Very nice! Not a single loop in sight. Taking complete advantage of built-in vectorization. Regarding @Fractal's request if it's possible to do better, all of the built-in R function's you're using are already written in C or Fortran, correct? + for example is a .Primitive. Maybe the subsetting reassignments (res[i] and res[!i] can be sped up somehow? Profiling R Code. Lastly, is it actually necessary to get any faster?

pre-allocate (eta - 1) (and (1 - eta))?
